# Woocommerce How to replace the sale price of out of stock products but keep the Regular price?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product

I am not good at code, and I am stuck in this situation. Our products have 2 prices:

- The Retail Price
- The Sale off Price.

I want to replace the Sale off Price of 'Out of stock' Products with 'SOLD OUT' text and still keep the Retail Price, also remove the 'Sale percent' badge on product image.

I'm using [Replace displayed price by a text for out of stock WooCommerce products](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65964151/11987538) answer code which works great but it replace all Prices to SOLD text and I do not know how to code it to my needs.

Comment: This question is asked before - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65963520/replace-displayed-price-by-a-text-for-out-of-stock-woocommerce-products

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replace displayed price by a text for out of stock WooCommerce products](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65963520/replace-displayed-price-by-a-text-for-out-of-stock-woocommerce-products)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
add_filter('woocommerce_get_price_html', 'change_sold_out_product_price_html', 100, 2 );
function change_sold_out_product_price_html( $price_html, $product ) {
    if ( ! $product->is_in_stock() ) {
        $regular_price = wc_price($product->get_regular_price());
        $price_html = __($regular_price."SOLD", "woocommerce");
    }
    return $price_html;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks for your code. The code works, but the currency is still there, how can I remove it? Thanks

Comment: I use this code from @LoicTheAztec and it remove currency symbol. Thanks
`code`
add_filter('woocommerce_currency_symbol', 'change_existing_currency_symbol', 10, 2);
function change_existing_currency_symbol( $currency_symbol, $currency ) {
    $product = wc_get_product( get_the_ID() );

    if ( is_a( $product, 'WC_Product' ) && $currency === 'USD' && ! $product->is_in_stock() ) {
        $currency_symbol = ''; 
    }

    return $currency_symbol; 
}
`code`

Comment: Please Replace $regular_price = wc_price($product->get_regular_price());  to $regular_price =$product->get_regular_price();

Comment: If I replace the code as you gave above, the Regular price will return in number and they have no thousand separator each 3 number, like $1,000,000 will be 1000000. I use the second code I added and it will remove the currency symbol in Sale Price (of out of stock product). Would you please help me add <span class="regular-price-for-sold-out">regular price</span> to style this Regular Price text and a class for SOLD text?

Comment: Are you want to remove only currency symbols from the price?

Comment: function custom_wc_price( $return, $price, $args, $unformatted_price, $original_price ){ 
 return $price;
} 
add_filter('wc_price', 'custom_wc_price', 10, 5);

Comment: Thank you Sir, finally I found the way how to custom the code for my needs with your instructions. Here is my final code:

Comment: add_filter('woocommerce_get_price_html', 'change_sold_out_product_price_html', 100, 2 );
function change_sold_out_product_price_html( $price_html, $product ) {
    if ( ! $product->is_in_stock() ) {
        $regular_price = wc_price($product->get_regular_price());
        $price_html = __("<del aria-hidden='true'>".$regular_price."</del>".'<ins>'.' SOLD'.'</ins>', "woocommerce");
    }
    return $price_html;
}